# Binding to dataGrid SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have DataGrid like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="{Binding ???}" BorderBrush="Black" >
                        <Grid></Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

And I need to bind BorderThickness of Border in CellTemplate to DataGrid.SelectedItem. For example: if cell is in selected row thickness must be 1,1,1,1 else zero. (I know about converters). How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved using triggers:

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border  BorderBrush="Black" >
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>

                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>
                            <Grid></Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**OR**

Directly set CellStyle like

```
       <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>

                    </Style>
```

Comment: Try now.. you will have to set the Value=True on DataTrigger Or alternative approach is suggested

Comment: No, I need to use template, because I have a lot of binded content inside the border.

Comment: you can still use template. Just set the Cell border using the trigger I showed. and in template dont add border.

Comment: I'm just need my own border, or maybe circle or anything else. I need to know, how to bind this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Converters may not be the way to go with this, try using a datatrigger on the selected grid item which changes the border style, have a gander at this http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/